# How to programmatically create a BasicHttpBinding?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, service-model

I have to following code:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding ();

Uri baseAddress = new Uri ("URL.svc");

EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress (baseAddress);

var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyInterface> (binding, endpointAddress);

IMyInterface client = null;

try
{
    client = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel ();
    var a = client.WsFunction ("XXXXXX");                    
    ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close ();
}
catch
{
    if (client != null)
    {
        ((ICommunicationObject)client).Abort ();
    }
}
```

Where "IMyInterface" is the interface that my WS implements.. for example:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    Result WsFunction1 (string param);

    [OperationContract]
    Result WsFunction2 (string param);

    [OperationContract]
    Result WsFunction3 (string param);
}
```

And it returns something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    string a = "";
    string b = "";

    [DataMember]
    public string A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set { b = value; }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I can reach the WS, but I can never get the Result filled out.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That wouldn't compile, little a is of type string, big A is of type bool.

Comment: It's because I changed the names... but actually it compiles and WS receives the message... but I can't get the result..

Comment: Result namespace is one of probale culprits but I would start from sniffing the traffic with an http debugger.

Comment: Using Fiddler I can see that I can reach the WS perfectly! But Result is the guilty... always null...

Comment: can you show your implementation of IMyInterface?

Comment: It's in the post =) ...I just changed the names... but actually, I have 3 methods that return a "Result" (DataContract)

Comment: When there is a xml namespace mismatch, the response reaches the client but is not deserialized correctly. Could be just happening to you.

Comment: But it woulnd't return an exception? Actually I copied the DataContract from WS... =/ ...guess it's correct

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do it "by hand"? Perhaps generating a proxy with SvcUtil (in VS Console) will give you a perfect proxy for that. If you want more information on what is going on, just read that proxy code.

Comment: I want to make a dll and remove the app.config step =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to access a service via a `BasicHttpBinding` is to generate the client code from SlSvcUtil.exe, which is a silverlight utility application.

```
SLsvcUtil.exe /directory:C:\users\me\Desktop http://URL.svc
```

That should create a MyInterfaceClient class inside of the file it generates.

Then in your code you can do:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding() {
    Name = "BindingName",
    MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
};

var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("URL.svc");

MyInterfaceClient client = new MyInterfaceClient(binding, endpoint);

client.WSFunctionCompleted += (object sender, WSFunctionCompletedEventArgs e) => {
    //access e.Result here
};

client.WSFunctionAsync("XXXXXX");
```

Your mileage may vary. Let me know if this works.

Comment: leveraging SvcUtil will yield similar results. But I think the whole question is about doing it "by hand".

Comment: I figure it will at least give him code to read to figure it out. I don't see why he would need to do it without SvcUtil though.

Comment: Guess it's what I need!! Thank you Millie!!

Answer (score 3):

```
 var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.ProxyAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", proxyAddress, proxyPort));
        binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;

        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("serviceadress");

        var authenticationClient = new WOKMWSAuthenticateClient(binding, endpoint);
        authenticationClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        authenticationClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

if you want to run it on your local you should this code.

```
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy and simple way to call WCF :

```
            BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:3283/Service1.svc");

            myBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
            myBinding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

            ChannelFactory<ITestAPI> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ITestAPI>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

            ITestAPI instance = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

            Test data = new Test();
            data.helloName = name;
            data= instance.GetMyName(data);

            myChannelFactory.Close();
```