# Setup http proxy in order to to invoke WCF service reference

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, wcf

I added a WCF service reference to external soap web service. It's all good until i publish the solution to an internal machine which need to setup a proxy (with Basic auth user/password) to be able to invoke WS.

In .net framework, it was just add a section config to setup the proxy. I need the same in a .net 6 project..
I already tried to create a CustomBinding object to wrap BasicHttpBinding, in order to set the proxy but without success...
Anybody can give me some tips to achieve that? Do you have any sample with this use case?

```
smsClient = new SubmissionManagerClient();

SetProxySettings(smsClient, !string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.Address), settings.Address, settings.Port, settings.Username, settings.Password);
     
retval = smsClient.sendSmsSubmission(authInfo, smsSubmission);

        private void SetProxySettings<TChannel>(ClientBase<TChannel> client,
            bool useProxy, string address, int port, string login, string password)
            where TChannel : class
        {
            if (!useProxy) return;

            var b = client.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;
            if (b == null)
            {
                this.logger.LogWarning("Binding of this endpoint is not BasicHttpBinding");
                return;
            }

            b.ProxyAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", address, port));
            b.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
            b.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None; 
            b.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;

            if (client.ClientCredentials == null)
            {
                this.logger.LogWarning("client.ClientCredentials is null");
                return;
            }            

            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = login;
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
        }
```

Error message

```
2022-05-03 22:15:33.1715|ERROR|00-9bcc09397d897a49b6f6ea013c203147-c68511c7504cf944-00|Altice.InfrastructureCore.SmsExpress.MessageSender|Error sending sms. System.ArgumentException: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. (Parameter 'via')
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelFactory`1.ValidateScheme(Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.ValidateCreateChannelParameters(EndpointAddress remoteAddress, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.OnCreateChannelCore(EndpointAddress remoteAddress, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.OnCreateChannel(EndpointAddress remoteAddress, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelFactoryBase`1.InternalCreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelFactoryBase`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.ServiceChannelFactoryOverRequest.CreateInnerChannelBinder(EndpointAddress to, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.CreateServiceChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.CreateChannel[TChannel](EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannel()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelInternal()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.get_Channel()
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any error message? .net 6 calls wcf to ensure the download requires the [nuget package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5#windows-communication-foundation). You can check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951523/how-can-i-set-an-http-proxy-webproxy-on-a-wcf-client-side-service-proxy).

Comment: @LanHuang i added the error message. I'm using the last version (4.9.0) of System.ServiceModel.Duplex, System.ServiceModel.Federation, System.ServiceModel.Http, System.ServiceModel.NetTcp and System.ServiceModel.Security.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `TransportCredentialOnly` instead of `Transport` in binding safe mode.
**EDIT**
Maybe you can try the code below:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.ProxyAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", proxyAddress, proxyPort));
        binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;

        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("serviceadress");

        var authenticationClient = new WOKMWSAuthenticateClient(binding, endpoint);
        authenticationClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        authenticationClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

Make sure that the securitymode of the server and client is the same.
useful links:
[The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435823/the-provided-uri-scheme-https-is-invalid-expected-http-parameter-name-via)

 https://stackoverflow.com/a/48008591/17218587

Comment: i know that. I'm invoking the service with HTTPS with a http proxy (which requires authentication)

Comment: Maybe you can check the `security mode` on the server side.